# Which expansion do I use for $\ln(x)$ if I have no knowledge of what $x$ is greater than or less than?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I’m trying to do expansions for $\ln$ and logs in honors Algebra 2, but I can’t figure this out! The equation I’m working on at the moment is $\ln15x$. I got to $\ln15+\ln x$, but I don’t know how to simplify it more! Note: this is probably a very simple concept, but I have been sick for a few months, so I have no idea what I’m doing for the most part and the internet isn’t helping.

Comment: $\ln15=\ln3+\ln5$

Comment: $\ln 15+ \ln x$ already looks simplified enough to me.

Comment: I agree with @SaucyO'Path, but it sounded like you wanted more; by the way, $\ln 15x$ is an expression, not an equation

Answer (score 1):

If the question as stated was: $$\text{Expand the expression}\space \ln(15x)\space\text{using logarithm rules.}$$ Then apply the law: $$\ln(xyz)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)+\ln(z)\implies$$ $$\ln(15x)=\ln(3\cdot5\cdot x)=\ln(3)+\ln(5)+\ln(x)$$